# Combining frequent n-gram features with dictionary features

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I'm classifying a corpus of reviews and I want to try out combining features such as readability score, number of syllables, etc. with the most frequent k n-grams. I've extracted the top k n-grams with NLTK in Python My first type of features are in a dictionary

```
{'readability':9, 'num-syllables':2}
```

I'm wondering if there's a right way to do this? I was thinking of just inserting the popular n-grams into the dictionary like in the following

```
{'readability':9, 'num-syllables':2, '('red', 'book')':True}
```

I couldn't seem to find implementations online, even though I've read about using most frequent n-grams in papers. So I don't know if I interpreted the idea of, say, "using the most 5000 frequent n-grams" correctly. Is this the correct way of implementing this for NLTK or Sci-kit learn or am I really far off base?

Thanks